# run single *.cs script from command line

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Is there at last a easy way to execute c# script file from command line?

I saw that [discussion on github](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/59)

and according to this thread i think `dotnet run Test.cs` should do the job.

But for my testclass which is:

```
using System;
namespace Scripts
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("This is the miracle");
        }
    }
}
```

it fails

```
PM> dotnet run .\Test.cs 
dotnet.exe : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.At line:1 char:1
```

So how could I execute the code in single file using command line in relatively easy manner?

---

UPD 1: As correctly mentioned by @Lee and @svick `dotnet run` is for running project. But my initial question was - how to run single file. Maybe some options using `roslyn`?

Comment: check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it might help you.

Comment: That link is very old. [Here is the current documentation for `dotnet run`.](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/core-sdk/cli/dotnet-run.html)

Comment: @MANISH That's not very relevant to `dotnet` CLI.

Comment: There now exists the concept of a C# script - see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405941/what-are-csx-c-sharp-files-for. Conceptually, this should get you what you want.

Comment: See also [How to compile and run a single class file cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712125/how-to-compile-and-run-a-single-class-file-cs-file)

Answer (score 30):

I found another solution on Scott Hanselman's blog:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CAndNETCoreScriptingWithTheDotnetscriptGlobalTool.aspx

It relies on a .NET CLI tool called `dotnet-script`, you can find its repository below:

https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script

To use, it, first install it using `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-script`

Then you can run `dotnet script` and use it as a REPL or run `dotnet script file.csx` to run a file.

To include a NuGet package reference, use `#r "nuget: AutoMapper, 6.1.0"`.

Answer (score 13):

**PowerShell one liner** out of the box

```
(Add-Type -Path "Program.cs" -PassThru)::Main()
```

P.S. In your particular case the `Main()` method has `args` parameter and it will complain that it's missing. In that case call `Main($null)`

Comment: How would you do this with the newer no-Program-class style CS file?  Like the file literally contains nothing more than System.Console.WriteLine("Hello");

Comment: @JoshMouch even if you use "top level statements" the build still generates a `Main` method for you. Check this out https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIMIHsB2BndAbAUwDoB1AJwEsAXAgCgCIbsr6BKAbiA The method might be named differently though. Try `Main$` or `$Main`

Answer (score 5):

It can be done using Powershell. 
Assumed, your code is in a file `test.cs` in the current folder:

```
$source = (Get-Content .\test.cs) -join " "
Add-Type $source -Language CSharp  
[Scripts.Program]::Main((""))
```

gives

```
PS> .\test.ps1
This is the miracle
```

> So how could I execute the code in single file using command line in
>   relatively easy manner?

Wrap the above code into a function, make the file name an parameter, put that function in your Powershell profile and run it whenever you want. But be aware of the fact, that as soon as you need other assemblies they must be specified when doing the call. [Here's a slightly more elaborat example](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/).

Comment: Note that using `-join " "` will put the entire contents of the program onto one line. If the program contains a comment `//` then the rest of the program will be commented out. To avoid this, use ``-join "`r`n"`` instead.

Comment: @benrwb or you could use `Get-Content -raw` and it won't split the content into lines in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

For this i've always used this c# scripting engine : http://csscript.net,

very easy to implement and works very well and you can reference local dlls, Nuget packages or GAC assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you'll need a project.json file. Here's a bare bones file to get it running:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": {}
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  }
}
```

Note the `emitEntryPoint`.

I had to `dotnet restore` first and then `dotnet run test.cs`.

Comment: so this options is only for projects and don't allow run single scripts, right?

Comment: I think so yeah, but if someone could confirm that would be good. I notice if you do a "dotnet new" it creates two files. A "Hello World" Program.cs and a simple project.json file.